# XSLT using for-each to apply templates

Tags: xml, xslt, soap

So, I asked a question earlier : [XSLT selecting mulitple nodes with different namespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27493801/xslt-selecting-mulitple-nodes-with-different-namespaces)

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:head="http://www/example.com">
  <soap:Header>
      <head:sampleHeaderType>
        <head:messageId>xxxxxxxx</head:messageId>
         <head:SID>XXX</head:SID>
         <head:BID>SP</head:BID>
         <head:CTS>2014-09-26T13:19:30.534Z</head:CTS>      
      </head:sampleHeaderType>
   </soap:Header>
   <soap:Body>
      <cass:SPD xmlns:cass="http://blahblahblah">
         <cass:SPR>
            <cass:RQ RT="Describe" FG="LOL" PD="09/22/2014" />
         </cass:SPR>
         <cass:SPS>
            <cass:SP SPT="Standard" FT="Retail" PS="New" ICT="APR" >
               <cass:DR DN="306532" BR="0.0790000">
                  <cass:FFMR ValueType="$" Value="0"/>
                  <cass:RV ReserveType="DP">
                     <cass:RTS TT="DP">
                        <cass:RT TMin="0" TMax="0.999999" TVT="%" TV="100"/>
                     </cass:RTS>
                  </cass:RV>
               </cass:DR>
               <cass:Product PID="Sirius" PN="Sirius"/>
            </cass:SP>
            <cass:SP SPT="Standard" FT="Retail" PS="New" ICT="APR">
               <cass:DR DN="306532" BR="0.1520000">
                  <cass:FFMR ValueType="$" Value="0"/>
                  <cass:RV RT="DP">
                     <cass:RTS TT="DP">
                        <cass:RT TMin="0" TMax="0.999999" TVT="%" TV="100"/>
                     </cass:RTS>
                  </cass:RV>
               </cass:DR>
               <cass:Product PID="Sirius" PN="Sirius"/>
            </cass:SP>
         </cass:SPS>
         <cass:SPMS>
            <cass:SPM MessageCode="" MessageType="" MessageText=""/>
         </cass:SPMS>
</cass:SPD>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

And now I have the stylesheet

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:cass="http://blahblahblah" xmlns:head="http://www/example.com" exclude-result-prefixes="soap cass head">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
   <xsl:template match="soap:Header" />
   <xsl:template match="cass:SPD">
            <xsl:for-each select=".//cass:SP">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:SPM"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:RQ"/>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:SP"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:template>


        <xsl:template match="*/cass:RQ">
        <RT>
            <xsl:value-of select="@RT"/>
        </RT>
        <FG>
            <xsl:value-of select="@FG"/>
        </FG>
        <PD>
            <xsl:value-of select="@PD"/>
        </PD>
        </xsl:template>

        <xsl:template match="*/cass:SPM">
            <MESSAGE_TXT>
                <xsl:value-of select="@MessageText"/>
            </MESSAGE_TXT>
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

So, basically for each cass:SP I want to generate seperate EVAPP_SP elements, which has nodes selected from different parts of the xml. I hope that was clear enough, I am not good at articulating this question.

Comment: The `xsl:template` elements must be top-level elements (children of `xsl:stylesheet`) while an `xsl:for-each` can only appear inside of a template.

Comment: Ok, I updated it, but I am still getting a blank xml output.

Comment: The `xsl:template` elements need to be children of `xsl:stylesheet`, not children of `CALL_ENGINE_RESPONSE`. Are you sure you don't get an error with your code?

Comment: Hey, I am really sorry if I am not understanding what you are saying. I updated my stylesheet in the question. Is it still wrong? I removed all the other additional tags, I will add them on later.

Comment: The stylesheet is fine now, but still does not produce any output. Please show the output you expect - in XML, not in prose. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurs in the template matching `cass:SPD`

```
<xsl:template match="cass:SPD">
    <xsl:for-each select=".//cass:SP">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:SPM"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:RQ"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:SP"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

So, within the template you are initially positioned on the `cass:SPD`. You then do a `for-each` to get `cass:SP` at any level under this. So far, so good. But then you use the xpath expression `*/cass:SPM`. Because within the loop your context is now on `cass:SP`, this will look for `cass:SPM` elements that are grand-children of `cass:SP`. But there are none. `cass:SPM` is a grand-child of `cass:SPD`.  Similarly for `cass:SR`.

It's hard to give a precise answer without knowing what output you wish to achieve, but it is possible the `for-each` is not actually needed here at all

```
<xsl:template match="cass:SPD">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:SPM"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:RQ"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/cass:SP"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This would at least give some output.